# Swing JDialog box appear itself?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

```
public Action colorAction = new AbstractAction("Font Color", new ImageIcon(
        getClass().getResource("/img/color.png"))) {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        colorB_actionPerformed(e);
    }
};

public void colorB_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(getRightPanel(), "Font color",
            Color.CYAN);
    if (c == null)
        return;
    new StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction("", c).actionPerformed(e);
}
```

Above are the code I use to display the Color chooser dialog. My question is, I never even start run or compile the program. But the color chooser dialog will appear automatically?

```
public void linkActionB_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(getJPanel(), "Enter URL :");

    String aTag = "<a";
    aTag += " href=\"" + value + "\"";

    aTag += ">" + value + "</a>";
    if (editor.getCaretPosition() == document.getLength())
        aTag += "&nbsp;";
    editor.replaceSelection("");
    try {
        editorKit.insertHTML(document, editor.getCaretPosition(), aTag, 0,
                0, HTML.Tag.A);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

as well as the show link dialog will also appear automatically, when I was still coding. Any idea?

Comment: I open it using eclipse visual editor. Is it normal, if open with visual editor then the dialog box will pop up automatically? Because when I open it with java editor the dialog box won't pop up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I bet you are working with an IDE of some sort and you have some instances of past runs or debug sessions that are still alive. Check and close all running/debugging JVM's and start fresh with a new one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replied, I restart the eclipse IDE and once I open the file the dialog will appear haven't even start run or compile the file

Comment: do you have an autorun set somewhere? things dont just run, something must start it.

Comment: if working in windows, go to task manager and kill all java processes you find. than start the eclipse IDE

Comment: No don't have any autorun, and kill all the java processes already once restart the eclipse IDE if open the file the dialog box appear.

Comment: Go to where your class files are, delete them. will it appear again?
Than compile to recreate the class file and start the IDE, does it appear now?

Comment: ya it appear again, once load the file, the dialog will open automatically